# How to know if I had scanned a file on VirusTotal?

Tags: antivirus

A few weeks ago, I was using VirusTotal to check a few files on my computer to see if they were viruses. But I do not remember if I had scanned a particular file. Is there is a way to check that? And if the file had sensitive information on it any recommendation on how to deal with that?

One of the ways that I was thinking about is to see if VirusTotal has an option to scan a file without uploading it to its database, since every time it scans, it shows the date of the last time that that file was scanned.

Comment: Check your browser history ...

Comment: hash the file and search the hash on virus total.They index those

Comment: I checked them in incognito so are there any other solution for this and may I also ask how can you hash a file and search it?

Comment: These are all questions for VirusTotal support. You need to work with them. You can read their [Privacy Policy](https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002168385-Privacy-Policy) for the specifics on personal files and your options about that.

Comment: How to search for a previously scanned file: https://support.virustotal.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002739245-Searching